# Deduce Schur-Zassenhaus theorem from Wedderburn-Malcev theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups

Is it possible to derive Schur-Zassenhaus theorem from Wedderburn-Malcev theorem? For the existance part I have the following idea: Let $G$ be a finite Group and $N$ an abelian Hall $p$-subgroup. Let $K$ be a field containing $p$ elements. We Focus on the natural epimorphism from $G$ onto $G/N$. This map can be enhanced to an algebra epimorphism from $KG$ onto $K(G/N)$. The kernel of this map is known: $KG\cdot Aug(KN)=Aug(KN)\cdot KG$. The Augmentation ideal $Aug(KN)$ is nilpotent based on a theorem of Wallace. Thus, $KG\cdot Aug(KN)=Aug(KN)\cdot KG$ is nilpotent, too. $N$ is a Hall subgroup, and hence $G/N$ is a $p'$-subgroup. Hence, $K(G/N)$ is semisimple by a theorem of Maschke. We deduce that $KG\cdot Aug(KN)=Aug(KN)\cdot KG$ is exactly the radical of $KG$. In addition, $K(G/N)$ is separable. By using the theorem of Wedderburn-Malcev a complement $T$ of $rad(KG)$ exists in $KG$: $KG=T\oplus rad(KG)$. We deduce that $E(KG)$ is the semidirect product of $E(T)$ and the nilpotent normal subgroup $1+rad(KG)=1+KG\cdot Aug(KN)$. $N$ is a subgroup of $1+rad(KG)$. Is it possible to control the intersection of $E(KG)$ and $G$?

Comment: we should close the topic.